# Remote mysql connection works in workbench but not in python

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I setup a mysql server (using mariadb) and database on my raspi and am now trying to connect to it from my MacBook.

Version:
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.38-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnueabihf (armv7l) using readline 5.2

The connection works in Workbench(on the Mac)but I can't get it to connect in python or command line

the /etc/my.cnf on the raspi looks like this:

bind-address = 0.0.0.0

[mysqld]

I have added a superuser with all permissions and am trying to connect on my Mac command line with this:

```
mysql -u {superuser} -p {superuser} -h '192.168.x.x' -P '3307' -D {securities_master}
```

Which doesn’t work.

In python I have tried different variations of this:

```html
host = '192.168.x.x'
user='superuser'
password='superuser'
database='securities_master'

import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=user, password=password, host=host, port='3307')
print(cnx.get_server_info())
```

command line returns this:
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 3

python script returns this:
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.x.x' ([Errno 61] Connection refused)")

Workbench connection is solid

Comment: Workbench is running on the Mac

Comment: I can't figure out how to update the Macs firewall from the link you posted

Comment: I apologize, I read the configuration in reverse, as the Mac was hosting mysql, and you were using the raspi to connect to the mysql instance hosted by the Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just same issue solved like that:

1. check if your mysql has granted "root" or "youruserID" the right to access from localhost(127.0.0.1) and LAN(192.168.x.x) the DB privileges? For this just ssh into remote server and:

   ```
    $ mysql -u root -p
    mysql> SHOW GRANTS
   ```

   For me it shows:

   ```
    Grants for root@localhost 
   ----------
   | GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD ‘*———‘ WITH GRANT OPTION |
   | GRANT PROXY ON ''@'%' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                                                             |
   ```

   which means it has been granted privilege from anywhere(@'%') incl. localhost(127.0.0.1)
2. python access remotely you need to install mysql connector:

   ```
    $ pip install mysql-connector-python
   ```
3. within Python3 you can try this (if mariaDB the port is 3307, default mysql is 3306):

   ```
    >>> import mysql.connector
    >>> cnx =mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='xxx', host='yourraspyi_sql_ip', port='3307')
    >>> print(cnx.get_server_info())
   ```

Comment: The user superuser in my case has same permissions as root. What do u mean by check if they have access to local host and ip?

Comment: as Sadi mentioned, the connection cmd line  -P 22 means your port is 22, this is not correct! 22 is normally for SSH, for mysql the port is 3306 and if mariaDB is 3307, this was also my problem, missing the port!
if ssh into raspi and login to mysql, better don't add any port in cmd line, just use: " mysql -u root p", just to check if mysql is running and accessible locally.

Comment: when I log in as root and ask to show grants it looks the same as yours, but your python code doesn't work for me

Comment: remember if you are using mariaDB the port is 3307!

Comment: pls go step 1. print out "SHOW GRANTS"

Comment: this is for root: | GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket USING '*9C0818C272CE7A0838E4E69B53E7745895C45D31' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'%' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION

Comment: this for superuser:  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'superuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*F5AB3475E4D0309381498567B7C7A270ADED2652' WITH GRANT OPTION

Comment: it means root can access from anywhere, then try use root from macBook as from step 3. pls. enter root and correct ip address for rasspi and port.
(PS: hope mysql connector has been correctly installed as step 2)
----- 
superuser has not been granted access from anywhere(@'%'), use this in ssh :

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'superuser'@'%';

Comment: python line cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='root_password', host='192.168.1.105', port='3307') is still giving me error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.105' (61)

Comment: double check the IP and pasword, and maybe you have firewall @ raspi? check from mac if the mariaDB server port is open:
$ nc -zvw3 raspi_ip 3307

Comment: $ nc -zvw3 192.168.1.105 3307
nc: connectx to 192.168.1.105 port 3307 (tcp) failed: Connection refused

Comment: bingo! you found the problem, then you should check raspi how to open the port. => cf. firewall setting.
found something for you: https://howtoraspberrypi.com/enable-mysql-remote-connection-raspberry-pi/

Comment: using sudo ufw allow 3307/tcp? just did this and its still refusing. do I need to reboot?

Comment: $sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
3306/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
3307                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
3307/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere

Comment: check the link above and restart mysql or reboot: 

(edit /etc/mysql/my.cnf and change port 3307 then 
sudo service mysql restart)

Comment: my /etc/mysql/my.cnf file is pretty much empty. I read somewhere else that I should instead edit the /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf file, which indeed has lots of stuff pre-written in it. so I changed the binding dress line to 0.0.0.0 and the port was at 3306, I changed to 3307. still no luck. thank you so much for helping me out this is driving me crazy

Comment: wait now nc -zvw3 192.168.1.105 3307 returned
found 0 associations
found 1 connections:
     1: flags=82<CONNECTED,PREFERRED>
 outif en0
 src 192.168.1.108 port 55766
 dst 192.168.1.105 port 3307
 rank info not available
 TCP aux info available

Connection to 192.168.1.105 port 3307 [tcp/opsession-prxy] succeeded!

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that `mysql -u {superuser} -p {superuser} -h '192.168.x.x' -P '22' -D {securities_master}` Works properly.

Here, the mysql connection port is 22. If that really works, then

```
host = '192.168.x.x'
user='superuser'
password='superuser'
database='securities_master'

import pymysql.cursors
connection = pymysql.connect(host=host,
                             port=3306,
                             user=user,
                             password=password,
                             db=database,
                             charset='utf8',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

should be

```
host = '192.168.x.x'
user='superuser'
password='superuser'
database='securities_master'

import pymysql.cursors
connection = pymysql.connect(host=host,
                             port=22,
                             user=user,
                             password=password,
                             db=database,
                             charset='utf8',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

The port number has changed to 3306 to 22.

you can check it with

```
pymysql.connect(db='securities_master', user='superuser', passwd='superuser', host='192.168.x.x', port=22)
```

Comment: No I’m sorry I mean that both the command line and python approaches are not working. I’ll try it again with different ports

Comment: @JoanArau In that case, can you please share the connection string that worked in mysql workbench? Also, you may want to take a look into the privilege section if that is somehow restrict the host. If it has such restriction, then the mysql workbench may work with SSH tunnel while other connections are failing. I am thinking about SSH tunnel as 22 is the default SSH port, and in mysql workbench you can see it if it uses the SSH tunnel.

Comment: Total beginner here, how can I see to connection string in workbench to show it to you?

Comment: this? superuser@127.0.0.1::3306. this command from workbench in the command line also works: "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/mysql" "-usuperuser" "-h127.0.0.1" -P50416  -p

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the localhost, did you host the mysql server in your local machine? You already mentioned it is remote, so in that case mysql workbench definitely used the tunnel. Login to the mysql using any admin tools like mysql workbench. Go to privilege, select the user, it may have only one entry with the host as `localhost`. Now create another entry with same username and password, but host will be `%`. Now try once more. `%` means any host.

Comment: In mysql workbench under users and privileges I have the following: root, localhost; superuser,localhost; superuser,%. both superuser have full privileges

Comment: looks like it was firewall issue and it was solved in previous answer by @NegOverflow